# Syntax error with session function on php5.3

Tags: php

The following function works on php 5.6 but gives error on php 5.3 which is the version of the cpanel im using. im unable to update the cpanel php version so i need to find a workaround..

```
 $url =isset($_SESSION['url']) ? $_SESSION['url'] : [];
```

the error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/mydomain/public_html/mypage.php on line 7
```

any workaround is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP 5.3 doesn't recognise the javascript style of array literals so you should instead do `$url =isset($_SESSION['url']) ? $_SESSION['url'] : array();`

Comment: that did it. thanks alot !

Comment: getting the same error on the following line, but dont know how to fix it since its a slightly different syntax.. `$total = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($cnn,"SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total"))['total'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array() instead of []. Yeah, it's PHP, not JavaScript.

Comment: getting the same error on the following line, but dont know how to fix it since its a slightly different syntax.. `$total = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($cnn,"SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total"))['total'];`